# Setting pre build event for nmake through command line in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, build, nmake

I am using Qt creator configured with tool chain Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 for building project. I am using third party libraries of ITK 4.3.0 which I manually added to .pro file of Qt project, it needs pre build event to build project. My problem is:

**1. For build as I am using `nmake` (not `jom.exe`) I want to involve a pre build event using macro `$(NOINHERIT)` but I don't know how to involve it while running `nmake` through command line?**

**2. I know how to set `nmake` for `Qt` creator but not how to set any pre build event using macro. I also know how to set `nmake` with release/debug configuration in Qt but not with macro.**

I hope if I get answer of 1st then I may try some tricks in Qt creator which may help to solve 2nd problem.

Comment: what is a "pre build command macro"? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Please refer this and sorry if i couldn't explained it properly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/42x5kfw4.aspx